# Wallets that support transfer hook

Tags: transfer, token-2022

I've been playing around with transfer hook, but for some reason neither phantom nor solflare seem to pick up the tokens that I have using that extension.  Solana explorer seems to display it correctly with the metadata:
https://explorer.solana.com/address/tMCXCCs6t9s9N3URwB3HgC3DhrfFV8U6ZETP8RAjgxs?cluster=devnet

but solscan does not
https://solscan.io/token/tMCXCCs6t9s9N3URwB3HgC3DhrfFV8U6ZETP8RAjgxs?cluster=devnet

do any 'standard' wallets support transfer hook yet or do i rely solely on my apps front end to handle transfers?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like solscan shows your transfer hook:

[image]

Token22 Meta data is not support everywhere yet. Just write any wallet and explorer that does not have support yet that you need it and they should add it.

Phantom also recently added support for transfer hooks:

https://twitter.com/phantom/status/1766546344892604923

Comment: oh, nice, they only mention ios but hopefully that is coming to browser/android soon